# How do I repent from swearing by something other than Allah, knowing it amounts to shirk?

Tags: sunni

Knowing swearing is shirk I did swear in Ramadan someone told me all the praying dua I’ve done is of no use what do I do now ? Please tell me are all my praying gone and is of no use